# Spring - should entity class consist method besides getX and setX?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have some experience with Django and its MVC (MTV rather...) concept. In my previous project in django, I always tried pack a lot of functions (methods) to `Model class` - all which could work on single entity in `Model` object. I know that in `Java EE` world, there is much more layers than 3, so how should I do it in `Spring`? For instance, where should I place function which sum up few properties of entity? Anyway, do models in spring are also called "model"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just apply good OO practices. If some behavior can be encapsulated in the Model class, then definitely put it in the Model class. For example, a Model having a `salary` and a `bonus` properties might of course have a `getTotalIncome` method which returns the sum of salary and bonus.

Of course, it shouldn't cross its own boudaries. If the computation of the total income necessitates the call of a service to apply some tax based on the current month and some configuration in the database, this becomes business logic and couples your model objet with the service layer, which should not be done. So the `getTotalIncome` method in this case should not exist anymore.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I would like to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, no, you dont add many functions in the model object itself.  And spring is all about good design.  In other words, the model should just be a container for the information representing model elements.  Everything that is done to the model should be done through things like DAO.  In spring my models usually look like this:

```
public class Car {
    private int id;
    private Engine engine;
    private Control steeringWheel;
    ...

    // getters and setters
}
```

With a DAO like:

```
public interface CarDao {
    public void add( Car car );
    public void update( int id, Car car );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could u extend a little your answer? Where should I put i. e. function which sum up 2 field of Model?

Comment: @Maqxiq, what specifically are you trying to sum up, and for what reason?  it makes a difference.  Give me an example of your 2 objects, what you are summing, and what you expect to do with the sum.

Comment: Well, I give u more sophisticated example: let's say I have model `player`. There is a game on 2D board, and in every turn player *must*  do a move. In `Django`'s model I could just define method like doMove(x,y) and another private one which check if new x and y is diffrent that previous. If all is OK object will be save (in db). How could I do that kind of buissness logic in java?

Answer (score 0):

It's less about layers and more about keeping data objects simple so that you can move them around your enterprise systems in whichever way you like without surprises. There's nothing about Spring itself that really cares how many methods you put in a class, but I agree with Lucas that keeping an entity class simple is better design.

Long experience has led me back to this conclusion many times. "Busy" entity objects end up being a pain sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I would have a model object for Player, one for Game, and maybe one for State.  I would have a DAO for each and, I would have a controller, perhaps called Controller that would perform all of the operations.  For example:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    ...
}

public class State {
    private Map<Player, Location> locations;
    private Map<Player, Health> healths;
    ...
}

public class Game {
    private Player player1;
    private Player player2;
    private State state;
    ...
}
```

With a standard CRUD like DAO (possibly with additional helper methods), and a controller that implements an interface something like this:

```
public interface Controller {
    public void move( Player player, Location location );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that code, but is it really should be controller? Imho controllers should return view - generate front end?

Comment: @Maxiq, In pure MVC the controller is there to handle the action, modify the model, and provide the view with the data it needs for presentation.  It literally _controls_ the application.  However, most people do not go to the full extent of pure MVC.  You can choose to use as much or as little of it as you want, but separation of concerns is almost always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE has changed a lot of patterns that were common in J2EE world. Although Spring is not Java EE it was designed around the same idea - to get rid of the legacy J2EE cumbersomeness. There's a good book by Adam Bien about J2EE patterns that have become anti-patterns - "[Real World Java EE Patterns. 
Rethinking Best Practices](http://press.adam-bien.com/)"

One of it chapters "Persistent Domain Object" answers exactly your question. *Model your application with real objects and don’t care about the persistence at the beginning... JPA turns out to be really flexible in mapping rich domain objects into relational tables. The more complex logic you have to realize, the easier object-oriented persistence can be maintained and developed.*